# To feel adjusted (phrase usage)

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say (and write), "I *feel/don't feel adjusted* to a house/country"?

For example:

> I *feel adjusted* to Las Vegas because it's my hometown.

Can someone really be *adjusted* or *feel adjusted* to a certain place?

The sentence I wish to use in my essay is:

> I *don't feel adjusted* to any house or country.

The meaning I intend to bring out is that I don't belong to any country and have no place to call home.

Answer (score 2):

What's throwing you off is the word "feel" as it's not necessary in this case.
You can just say "I've adjusted to life in Vegas", or "I haven't adjusted to the night life if Vegas yet".

Comment: Actually,I have a bit different sentence that I want to write in the essay:

Comment: here it is- I don't feel adjusted to any house or country.(The meaning is that I don't belong to no country and have no place to call home)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use adjusted, as it means to become accustomed, or re-orient yourself to that particular different environment you are in.
"I am well adjusted to the night life here in Las Vegas".
"I don't feel adjusted to living in Alaska in the winter mainly due to the extreme cold weather".

Comment: So saying "I don't feel adjusted to any house or country"(the meaning is that I don't belong to no country and have no place to call home) will be alright?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Also, in what context?
"I don't feel adjusted to any house or country, because I'm always looking for a new adventure / new challenge /".
"I don't feel adjusted to any house or country, because I'm not the type to settle down in one place"

Comment: The idea of the text I am writing is that my family is my home,so the whole sentence sounds like "My family is my home,I don't feel adjusted to any house or country".

Comment: Since my family is my home, I have no need to adjust to any one house or country?

Comment: The text is about home.They asked me to write what home means to me.So I wrote that I don't feel adjusted to any place as I've changed many places of living,so my family is my home.Like,the home for me is there the FAMILY is :)

Comment: "I had no need to get adjusted to living in any one house or place because my home is where my family is / go / travel"

Hows that ?

Comment: Was the previous statement better ?

Comment: Thank you!I just removed that phrase and made up another sentence with the same meaning!By the way,is it fine to say that I "made up" a sentence? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you could use:

> I don't feel at home in any house or country

This works with the update you gave in comments as to the context you wish to use.

Of course the classic phrase is:

> Wherever I lay my hat, that's my home

Which implies that it doesn't matter where you go, wherever you settle or are comfortable **is** your home

Comment: But do you think writing "My family is my home, I don’t feel adjusted to any house or country" is too wierd?Honestly,I just like the structure of the sentence.

Comment: "I don't feel adjusted" just doesn't work in this context.

Comment: Fine.Thanks for your comments!Still, can I somehow put the word FAMILY in the sentence?I just need it to be there! Maybe, like "I don't feel at home in any house or country, so my family means home to me" or that doesn't work too?